# In MongoDB: longer property names make bigger documents / use more memory?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, database

I use Mongo with its Java driver and Morphia. I am mapping this class:

```
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String transactionUniqueIdentifier;

}
```

I see in the console that Mongo saves a transaction in a form like `{transactionUniqueIdentifier: "xjeer"}`

Does it mean I should use shorter property names ("uuid" instead of "transactionUniqueIdentifier") to get a smaller database? Or is there a setting in Mongo which would deal with that for me (create shorter names internally...).
Any pointer would be appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With morphia, the document property names match the java field names by default.  You can name them however you'd like to be serialized into mongodb using the @Property annotation and providing whatever name you'd like.

Comment: Probably obvious but: even with my properties annotated with @Property, I will still be able to query my docs using their original Java names, right?

Comment: Yes.  Morphia will map that properly either way.

Comment: I use the @Property annotation a lot, but you need to be careful since you have two different names for the same field. Might just be better to use uuid for the Java field name too?

Answer (score 3):

There is no internal mapping of field names within MongoDB.

Whether or not to create shorter names depends upon numerous things, including usage of the document in Map Reduce, overall size of the document and hardware on your servers.

For example if your document is easier to handle in Map Reduce using `transactionUniqueIdentifier` rather than `uuid` and the document is quite small (let's say about 5KB each) and you have SSDs (probably not needed actually) then the shrinking of field names becomes almost useless.

Some would argue that it isn't but real world usage dictates that you have bigger things to worry about.

However, if you were to have a lot of fields with long names or you were you have longer names than `transactionUniqueIdentifier` then you might want to look into shortening them else you could be spending most of your time loading the field names of a document from disk instead of loading the actual values (since the fieldnames will be bigger than the total size of the documents values).

There are plans to compress the field names however, as of yet, other features have taken priority.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. My use case is simply that I'd like the db to fit on the hard drive I have at hand - I have no worry about speed of queries.The csv files that I import the data from are smallish, the MongoDB I import them into is huge in comparison. I thought that the repetition of these lengthy Strings for property names was a reason for this huge size of the db - you confirm this indeed plays a role.

Comment: @seinecle Indeed with that extra information you just told me I would say the "huge" part is definitely the field names in that case